# Slide animation when showing/hiding CustomTaskPane in VSTO

Tags: excel, animation, vsto, add-in, customtaskpane

I have a `CustomTaskPane` in my VSTO project that I can show/hide using `.Visible = true/false` property. However it's an ordinary showing/hiding element with no animation whatsoever.

However the "Smart Lookup" button, that comes with Excel 2016, also opens an Excel Pane by sliding left/right.

[image]

I guess that the Smart Lookup addin is built in the newer technology using JavaScript instead of the outdated VSTO COM plugin and thus might have such feature.

Am I able to have it in the VSTO plugin as well?

Answer (score 1):

It's the default behavior beginning with Excel 2013, that the task panes slide in / out. But this can be disabled in the registry, see [Disable Excel 2013 cell animation](https://superuser.com/questions/547832/disable-excel-2013-cell-animation):

**Please check that the registry setting is set to "DisableAnimations = 0"**

Then all your custom task panes should be slided in / out when setting visible true / false.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you need to install [KB3114383](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/3114383/december-8-2015-update-for-office-2016-kb3114383). With this KB installed, you can disable animations only for Custom Task Panes by changing the following registry key (depending on you your Microsoft Office version: 15.0 = 2013, 16.0 = 2016):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Toolbars
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Toolbars
```

Add the following DWORD value:

```
DisableWindowTransitionsOnAddinTaskPanes
```

... and set its value to 1. All other animations, even native task pane (such as Format Chart Area) animations, will remain unchanged. More info [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/3121687/it-takes-long-for-an-add-in-to-display-a-custom-task-pane-in-a-documen).